# Decomposition of primes in cyclotomic extensions and their ramifications

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-analysis, number-fields, local-fields, p-adic-numbers

Let $p$ be a prime. Suppose $L$ is a degree $p$ Galois extension over a number field $K$. Suppose $p$ splits both in $K$ and $L$.

So there will be $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$ primes of $K$ over $p$. Call them $v_1,...,v_{[K:\mathbb{Q}]}$. Now each of these $v_i$ will split into $p$-many primes in  $L$. Let $\mathfrak{B}_{j,v_i}$ be the primes of $L$ lying over $v_i$ for $j\in[1,p].$

Let $K_\infty$ and $L_\infty$ be the cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_p$ extension of $K$ and $L$ respectively. I know that the primes $v_i$ will ramify (and there will only be one prime say $\mathfrak{P}_{v_i}$) over $K_\infty$. So $\mathfrak{P}_{v_i}^{e_{v_i}}$ will lie over $v_i$, where $e_{v_i}$ is the ramification index of $v_i$ over $K_\infty$.

Now, similarly, $\mathfrak{B}_{j,v_i}$ will also ramify in $L_\infty$. Let $\mathfrak{G}_{j,v_i}$  be the prime of $L_\infty$ lying over $\mathfrak{B}_{j,v_i}$with ramification index $f_{j,v_i}$.

1. What is the relation between the ramification indices  $f_{j,v_i}$ and $e_{v_i}$?
2. Does $\mathfrak{P}_{v_i}$ split in $L_\infty$?
3. Let $L_{\infty,\mathfrak{G}_{j,v_i}} $ be the completion at $L_\infty$ at the prime
   $\mathfrak{G}_{j,v_i}$. What can be say about the local extension $L_{\infty,\mathfrak{G}_{j,v_i}} $ over $K_{\infty, \mathfrak{P}_{v_i}}$? Its $p$-cohomological dimension?

Thank you for your help in advance.